# Polynomial of degree $n$ with $n+1$ zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> > Prove that if $P $ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with $n+1$ zeros $P$ must be zero

This can be proven easily by the fundamental Theorem of Algebra. 
However, how would one prove the statement above without using the fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n$. W.L.O.G, let $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{n+1}$ be distinct values that are the solutions of $P(x) = 0$. We have
$$
\color{red}{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^n \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
1 & x_{n+1} & x_{n+1}^2 & \cdots & x_{n+1}^n 
\end{bmatrix}} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
\cdots \\
a_n
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\cdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The square matrix in red is called a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and is invertible. It turns out from linear algebra that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
\cdots \\
a_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\cdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 4):

You can easily prove, that if $a$ is a root of a polynomial $p$ the $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$. Thus, inductively we have $p(x)=(x-a_1)\cdot...\cdot(x-a_{n+1})q(x)$. Since the degree of a product is the sum of the degrees, we obtain $n=deg(p)=n+1+deg(q)$. But only possibility for this to hold is $q\equiv p\equiv 0$.