# Show that ${x_0^k\over \prod_{j\neq0} (x_0-x_j)}+{x_1^k\over \prod_{j\neq1} (x_1-x_j)}+...+{x_n^k\over \prod_{j\neq n} (x_n-x_j)}=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

Show that
$${x_0^k\over \prod_{j\neq0} (x_0-x_j)}+{x_1^k\over \prod_{j\neq1} (x_1-x_j)}+...+{x_n^k\over \prod_{j\neq n} (x_n-x_j)}=0$$
For $k=0,1,...n-1$ and for $k=n$
$${x_0^n\over \prod_{j\neq0} (x_0-x_j)}+{x_1^n\over \prod_{j\neq1} (x_1-x_j)}+...+{x_n^n\over \prod_{j\neq n} (x_n-x_j)}=1$$
I know this identity
$$x_0^kL_0(x)+x_1^kL_1(x)+...+x^k_nL_n(x)=x^k$$
Somehow I should be able to compare the coefficient of $x^n$ to the one above and get the result.  Let $P_n(x)$ interpolates $f(x)$ at n+1 nodes. So I can prove that
$$P_n(x)=f(x)$$
and the identity is shown.

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the determinant of the $\left(n+1\right)\times\left(n+1\right)$-matrix whose $i$-th row is $\left(x_0^i,x_1^i,\ldots,x_n^i\right)$ for all $i \leq n-1$ and whose $n$-th row is $\left(x_0^k,x_1^k,\ldots,x_n^k\right)$? Here, we are labeling the rows by $0,1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: What is $L_i$ in the identity?

Comment: L(x) is Lagrange polynomial

Comment: Lots of formulas with this shape can be proven using the nonlocal derangement identity, given as formula 1.20 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255987146).

Comment: What exactly is the obstacle for you to compare the leading coefficient on the left side of $\sum x_j^kL_j(x)$ with the coefficient of the same degree on the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Incomplete answer**. There is this [beatiful lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810645/polynomial-of-degree-n-with-n1-zeros/), that any polynomial of degree $n$ with more than $n$ roots is identically zero.

Now, [given that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) $L_j(x)=\prod\limits_{k=0,\\k\ne j}^n\frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}$ is of degree $n$, then 
$$P(x)=x^k-\sum\limits_{j=0}^nx_j^kL_j(x)$$
is of degree at most $n$ for $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, but it has $n+1$ roots $\{x_0,x_1,...,x_{n}\}$. Thus
$$x^k-\sum\limits_{j=0}^nx_j^kL_j(x)\equiv 0 \Rightarrow
x^k=\sum\limits_{j=0}^nx_j^kL_j(x)$$
and 
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^nx_j^kL_j(0)=0 \iff
\sum\limits_{j=0}^nx_j^k\prod\limits_{k=0,\\k\ne j}^n\frac{0-x_k}{x_j-x_k}=0 \iff\\
(-1)^n\left(\prod\limits_{k=0}^n x_k\right)\left(\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\frac{x_j^{k-1}}{\prod\limits_{k=0,\\k\ne j}^n(x_j-x_k)}\right)=0$$
or, assuming none of $x_k=0$
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\frac{x_j^{k-1}}{\prod\limits_{k=0,\\k\ne j}^n(x_j-x_k)}=0,
k\in\{1,2,...,n\} \iff \\
\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\frac{x_j^{k}}{\prod\limits_{k=0,\\k\ne j}^n(x_j-x_k)}=0,
k\in\{0,2,...,n-1\}$$

Comment: Seeing that $L_j(x)=\frac{x^n+...}{\prod_{m\ne j}(x_j-x_m)}$, it is really more simple to compare the leading coefficients instead of the constant coefficients.

Comment: @LutzL indeed, although, it was a bit of nostalgy and fun to recall some parts of my old phd thesis, Lagrange polynomial related in various normed spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If $R>\max|x_j|$ is  sufficiently large radius and $q(z)=\prod_{j=0}^n(z-x_j)$, then the denominators in the given formula are the derivative values $q'(x_j)$ and by the residue theorem of complex analysis
$$
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{z^k}{q(z)}dz=\sum_{j=0}^n\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{z^k}{q(z)}, x_j\right)=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{x_j^k}{q'(x_j)}.
$$
On the other hand, for $R\to\infty$ the left side converges to (and is in consequence already equal to it for all $R>\max|x_j|$)
$$
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{R^{k+1}z^k}{R^{n+1}z^{n+1}+O(R^{n})}dz
\to
\lim_{R\to\infty}R^{k-n}\cdot\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z^{n+1-k}}
=
\begin{cases}0,& k<n,\\1,&k=n.\end{cases}
$$